# Google Map not drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Below is my code minus the google map key. I do not get an error and I also do not get a map. What have I missed? You will have to add your on map key to try it you can get that here.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <title>Test Map</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="map_canvas" width="800" height="auto"></canvas>
  <script >

function initMap() {
  var map;var elevator;
  var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8403, -88.9548),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        };

  map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);
  var addresses = ['Decatur, Illinois'];
  for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addresses[x]
   + '&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
              var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
              new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latlng,
                  map: map,
                });
              console.log(p.lat);
            });
  }
}

  </script>
<script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY GOES HERE=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Google map can not be loaded to `canvas`. You need to use any block element, like `div, section, main etc.`

Comment: I used a DIV, with a height. I assume the above will fix your issue though.

Comment: There are four typos in the posted code: 1. no callback parameter in the API load 2. the element with id="map" must be a `<div>`,  3. the map  `<div>` must have a valid size. 4. missing ">" on final `<html>` [working version](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_noMap_20171122.html)

Comment: Like pointed out previously, element needs to be a `<div>` with set height. Working code (without key): https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/au34ejuj/

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick and silly idea - but have you tried giving it a explicit height? Mine wouldn't show without that.

ie 
    height="400px"

Comment: Missing height was an answer, is it just that I didn't state that clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

Change `<canvas id="map_canvas" width="800" height="auto"></canvas>` to `<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>`. You have to set the height auto will not work.

Also you need to run the initMap function by calling `initMap();`